# Constant current through a conductor is a problem of electrostatics or electrodynamics?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-current, potential, electrical-resistance

When you connect a constant voltage source across a resistor, there will be a constant current through the wires. Is this a problem of electrostatics or electrodynamics?

If it is a problem of electrodynamics then is there any concept of potential difference here?

Comment: since churches are moving it is not static, and the voltage is a potential difference

Comment: Magnetostatics.

Answer (score 0):

It is neither, it is a simple problem of electricity, known as Ohm's law. Voltage is just another term for (electrical) potential difference.

Electrostatics is the theory of charges which are *not* moving. Electrodynamics is the study of how changing or moving electric and magnetic fields behave. Neither applies to Ohm's law.